# Mysql - Access Denied - Can't touch program

Tags: mysql, xampp

This is more of a technical question, rather than a programming question.

A friend made and uses a program and it already works and has been compiled. Both of us have Windows 7. Friend said it requires Mysql for it to run. But the error says:

```
access denied for user 'specificUser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    <a bunch of Mysql error stacks with: MySqlStream.OpenSocket() : at the top>
```

The friend already set up the user and is sure the password and username are correct. The user also has access to the database, based on the privileges set on the user table.

Currently using XAMPP, with MySql 5.0. My friend uses MySql Administrator. Same error when I have MySql Administrator on, but weird thing is, it needs XAMPP to have MySql Service on. They both use port 3306.

So, what am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried to connect to DB from command line?

Comment: So far, I can connect at least using root. But since I don't know the password, I can't use the user that's used in the program.

-Edit- I also have access to the database using root.

Comment: Can our administrator try it? May be the userconfiguration in Db is not ok.

Comment: Darn... Here's what happened: I convinced my friend his password may be wrong. Friend deleted the old user and added a new one using a premade sql statement. It has worked before even before I had XAMPP. UNFORTUNATELY, it's not working now. Still same error. Even on command line.

Answer (score 0):

Check the connection in mysql.user table.
Whether such user is present or not?

And also try by changing your connection string from localhost to 127.0.0.1

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the user does exist. Also, as state on my title, I cannot touch the program. Thanks for the try though. Didn't check there until you told me. -Edit- Whoops. My friend did that, though. XD

Answer (score 0):

It seems my friend was using a wildcard for the host.

I tried making my own user earlier and the error didn't happen. Tracing the differences, I realized it was the host.

I changed "%" into "localhost". Might be better, since i'm working only on the localhost, and not online or a network.

======================================

Sorry, the information involved for the answer was not provided in the question.